# Creating html tables using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on creating HTML tables using PHP. I have created my database and tables but cannot figure out how to actually create the tables. There is a disconnect that I am missing somewhere, could someone please help me?  How would I convert this into code used to create an HTML database/table

```
create database testproject
use testproject
create table caller_info (caller_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
first_name varchar(35) not null, Last_name varchar(35) not null, franchise varchar(25) not 
null)  

create table caller_call_record(call_record_id int(11) not null, Call_Description varchar(50),
franchise_id int(10) not null, email varchar(40) not null, username varchar(25) primary key not
null);

create table caller_escalation
(
call_escalation_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment not null, 
Second_Level varchar(5) not null, 
caller_id int(11) unsigned not null, 
PRIMARY KEY(call_escalation_id),
username varchar(25) not null,  
FOREIGN KEY(caller_id) 
REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id),
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES caller_call_record (username)
);
```

I have also created a `delete` function and `update` function but like I said, I am lost as to how to actually create the table??
Here is the delete feature, I want to show that I have done the work but really need help putting it all together.

```
<html>
<title>Delete Call Log entry</title>
<style type="text/css" >

</style>

</head>

<body>

Franchise ID   First Name   Last Name    Email Address  </br><table border="3">

</table>

<h2>Delete Franchise Call Log</h2>
<form method="post" action="caller_info_test.php">


Enter Franchise ID record to delete <br />
<input type="text" name="franchise id" size="30" /><br />

<input type ="submit" value="Delete Call Log" name="submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my update feature

```
<html>
<title>Franchise Calls</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Franchise Call Log </h2>
<form method="post" action="caller_info_test.php">

First Name : <br />
<input type="text" name="first_name" size="30" /><br />

Last Name : <br />
<input type="text" name="last_name" size="40" /><br />

<input type ="submit" value=" Update Record" name="submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP I have created for the three tables:

```
<?php
//connect to the database - and create the caller_info table
include("inc_connect_local.php");
echo "Connected to mysql";

//Open the testproject database

mysql_select_db("testproject");
//create "caller_call_record" table
$query = "CREATE TABLE caller_call_record(
call_record_id int(11) not null,
Call_Description varchar(50),
franchise_id int(10) not null,
Email varchar(40) not null, 
Username varchar(25) primary key not null)
";

echo "Table created successfully.";
?>

<?php
//connect to the database - and create the caller_info table
include("inc_connect_local.php");
echo "Connected to mysql";

//Open the testproject database

mysql_select_db("testproject");
//create "caller_call_record" table
$query = "CREATE TABLE caller_call_record(
call_record_id int(11) not null,
Call_Description varchar(50),
franchise_id int(10) not null,
Email varchar(40) not null, 
Username varchar(25) primary key not null)
";

echo "Table created successfully.";
?>

<?php
//connect to the database - and create the caller_info table
include("inc_connect_local.php");
echo "Connected to mysql";

//Open the testproject database

mysql_select_db("testproject");
//create "caller_escalation" table
$query = "CREATE TABLE caller_escalation (
call_escalation_id int(11) unsigned auto_increment not null, 
Second_Level varchar(5) not null, 
caller_id int(11) unsigned not null, 
PRIMARY KEY(call_escalation_id),
username varchar(25) not null,  
FOREIGN KEY(caller_id) 
REFERENCES caller_info(caller_id),
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES caller_call_record (username)
)";
mysql_query($query);

echo "Table created successfully.";
echo "Franchise Call Log Database successfully created!";
```

Comment: You have the HTML, now you need the PHP. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Once you've got data in your database, you extract it with a select statement and present it to the user. However, you're going to need some PHP to do that, and that's something I don't see here.

Comment: You gonna need a little [tutorial](http://tutorial.world.edu/web-development/create-php-insert-select-update-delete-mysql-database-table/ "PHP To Insert, Select, Update, Delete In MySQL Database Table").

Comment: Aren't there examples of this kind of thing in every PHP tutorial? It's one of the most basic things to do.

Comment: I apologize, I told you I am very new at this and I have a disconnect.  I am looking at the tutorial provided by mdesdev now and upon the connection I have already gotten an error stating no database although it is created.

Comment: If you have a database connection problem, ask a question about the database connection problem and provide the relevant code. But that is not what you have asked here.

Comment: oh mamma mia, homework again huh @user3085177?

Comment: It's a project yes @Paul Dinham but I have done all of the work.  I just redid it all based on the tutorial that mdesdev gave me but what I have a disconnect on how to PHYSICALLY show an actual table.  I have created the database, tables, insert statement, update and the delete statements but how do I visually create the table.  That is the part I am missing and I know it is something small and im sure stupid but I am new at this and can not seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

First connect to the root account or another user with all privileges. Call a query on this string

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `YourNameHere`
```

Next create your table

```
CREATE TABLE `YourDatabaseName`.`YourTableName` (`value` char(1) NOT NULL, `OtherValue` varchar(40) NOT NULL, `ThirdValue` varchar(40) NOT NULL, `FourthValue` varchar(50) NOT NULL)
```

If you choose to use mysql_select_db then the command will be

```
CREATE TABLE `YourTableName` (`value` char(1) NOT NULL, `OtherValue` varchar(40) NOT NULL, `ThirdValue` varchar(40) NOT NULL, `FourthValue` varchar(50) NOT NULL)
```